# Actual moving of tablespaces in Postgres, not copy-delete

Tags: postgresql

I found that

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename SET TABLESPACE tablespacename
```

Copies the data and (I believe, couldnt check it) deletes the source after all is done. I need actual movement, because I have a large database that want to move to its own tablespace and doing this takes all the remaining storage.

Is any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such way.

PostgreSQL does not know about the underlying storage, so it doesn't know when to perform a hard link instead.

Besides, it makes no sense to have two tablespaces on the same file system, and with different file systems movement means copy + unlink anyway.

Comment: If not with tablespaces how can I move around the files of a specific database?

Comment: You cannot. Why would you want to do that? I don't understand the use case.

Comment: Lets say I have one database in a HD, but another DB is growing up a lot and I want to move it to it's own drive so it does not fills up the disk. So i purchase a new disk and now want to move my big database to the new one.

Comment: That will work just fine. After changing the tablespace, the file on the old disk will be removed. What more do you want in this situation?

Comment: Well, the thing is that in this case, a new drive means actually extend the space of an existing virtual drive in Linode that once extended cannot be shrinked (extra space = more money) and that's why I wanted to actually move the files not copy-delete. Now that I'm writing this, what I could do is just spin a new virtual drive, copy-delete the TS there and then move it back to the original virtual drive and delete the adhoc drive. Yeah. Thanks Laurenz.